# Setting the value of a PopUpMenuButton programmatically?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flex4.6

I need to set some initial values in several mx `PopUpMenuButton` components.  Based on [this Adobe info](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7b20.html) I am casting the component as a `Menu` and setting the `selectedIndex` – but it isn't working.

Any tips? The function gets called and it appears that the `selectedIndex` is set but the `PopUpMenuButton` still displays the first item in its data provider.

---

```
       private function initFontSizeData():void {
            Menu(fontSizePopUp.popUp).selectedIndex = 3; // 48 pt

            trace("index", Menu(fontSizePopUp.popUp).selectedIndex);
        }
```

---

```
    <mx:PopUpMenuButton id="fontSizePopUp" 
                        name="fontSizePopUp"
                        width="50" height="20"
                        labelField="label"
                        paddingLeft="-8"
                        itemClick="toolChangeHandler(event)"
                        open="canvasEnabled(false)"
                        close="canvasEnabled(true)"
                        chromeColor="#cccccc"
                        toolTip="Font Size"
                        styleName="toolPopUpStyle"
                        creationComplete="initFontSizeData()"
                        popUpStyleName="toolPopUpStyle">
        <mx:dataProvider>
            <fx:Array>
                <fx:Object fontPointSize = "18" label="18 pt"/>
                <fx:Object fontPointSize = "24" label="24 pt" />
                <fx:Object fontPointSize = "36" label="36 pt" />
                <fx:Object fontPointSize = "48" label="48 pt" />
                <fx:Object fontPointSize = "60" label="60 pt" />
                <fx:Object fontPointSize = "72" label="72 pt"/>
                <fx:Object fontPointSize = "96" label="96 pt" />
            </fx:Array>
        </mx:dataProvider>
    </mx:PopUpMenuButton>
```

Comment: Just a guess: What if you assign a different,  distinguishable dataprovider in `initFontSizeData()`? Maybe the method is executed before the value of the child tag is evaluated?

Comment: One last idea: does it make a difference if you create the dp in mxml, but in a fx:declarations like in the example code in the link in your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason that I ignore (maybe it's just a bug), the label of the `PopUpMenuButton` control is not updated and that's why you have to force it to do that using one of these methods :

- Using `mx.core.mx_internal` to commit the selected index :

```
Menu(fontSizePopUp.popUp).selectedIndex = 3;
Menu(fontSizePopUp.popUp).mx_internal::commitSelectedIndex(3);
```

- Dispatching an `mx.events.MenuEvent` event :

```
var menu_event:MenuEvent = new MenuEvent(MenuEvent.ITEM_CLICK);
    menu_event.index = 3;

Menu(fontSizePopUp.popUp).dispatchEvent(menu_event);
```

- Dispatching an `mx.events.FlexEvent` event :

```
Menu(fontSizePopUp.popUp).selectedIndex = 3;
Menu(fontSizePopUp.popUp).dispatchEvent(new FlexEvent(FlexEvent.VALUE_COMMIT));
```

Hope that can help.